# Доступ к хранилищу

Tags: android, permissions

Подскажите пожалуйста как дать доступ к хранилищу после нажатия на кнопку доунлоад.

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.download : {
                try {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folder8/";
                    File dir = new File (path);
                    if (!dir.exists())
                        dir.mkdir();
                    InputStream in = MyApplication.getContext().getAssets().open("wallpapp/" + wp.getWP());

                    File outFile = new File(path, wp.getWP());
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    copyFile(in, out);
                    in.close();
                    in = null;
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
                    MyApplication.getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(outFile)));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "((WP is saved in your Gallery))", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.like : {
                MyApplication.getFavoritesDatabase().addWP(WALP);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Added to favorites!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```